# MySQL – select rows which contain duplicates

Tags: mysql

How can I select only those rows which appear in query 1 and not query 2?
The goal is to find those reports which have multiple occurrences of the same item.

```
SELECT finance_report_id, finance_report_item_id FROM finance_report_values;

SELECT DISTINCT finance_report_id, finance_report_item_id FROM finance_report_values;
```

I was hoping something like the following would work. (This fails because `id` isn't selected in the second query.)

```
SELECT t1.finance_report_id FROM finance_report_values t1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT finance_report_id, finance_report_item_id FROM finance_report_values) t2
    ON  t1.id = t2.id
    WHERE t1.id IS NULL;
```

I suspect I'm not the first asking this, but I wasn't able to find the same problem posted.

Comment: Add `id` to the second query. And it should be `WHERE t2.id IS NULL`

Comment: `select finance_report_id, finance_report_item_id FROM finance_report_values GROUP BY finance_report_id, finance_report_item_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: If the goal is to find duplicates, why do you want the rows that *don't* appear in query 2?

Comment: Thank you for your comments! My question was correctly marked as a duplicate :)